# Can we show that $\int\mu({\rm d}x)\left|\int\mu({\rm d}y)p(x,y)(g(y)-g(x))\right|^2\le c\int\mu({\rm d}x)|g(x)|^2$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a probability space, $p:E^2\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E^{\otimes2}$-measurable with $$p(y,x)=p(x,y)\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in E\tag1$$ and $g\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)$ be nonnegative. Are we able to show that $$\int\mu({\rm d}x)\left|\int\mu({\rm d}y)p(x,y)(g(y)-g(x))\right|^2\le c\int\mu({\rm d}x)|g(x)|^2\tag2$$ for some $c\ge0$?

The "usual" inequalities are not sharp enough. Are we able to deduce the desired claim from $(1)$? Or do we need to impose further assumtpions?

Comment: There must be some further constraint on $p$, or else the LHS can be as large as you like by replacing $p$ with $\lambda p$ for arbitrarily large $\lambda$.

Comment: (1) is equivalent t $p(x,y)=p(y,x)$ for  all $x,y$. Inequality sounds strange.

Comment: @kimchilover You're right. This was a failed attempt to simplify my actual problem, which I've no described here (updated link): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3441067/47771

Comment: @KaboMurphy Sorry, it was supposed to be an equality. However, as noted in my previous comment, the claim won't hold and I've asked for my actual (but unfortunately more complicated) problem here (updated link): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3441067/47771.